# Ubuntu 16.04 tile windows no longer working

Tags: unity, 16.04, window-manager

At some point recently the tile windows feature stopped working for me. Hence if I drag a window to the left or right of the screen it no longer fills half the screen. Similarly, dragging a window to the top does not maximize it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> still maximizes

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> still minimizes

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> do not make the current window fill the left/right of the screen.

I am guessing this is a failed update somewhere. Does anyone know which packages to try reinstalling to regain this feature?

Comment: I'd like to see this bug addressed.  Does anyone know if a launchpad ticket was created?  ***NB:*** I'm only saying _bug_ sine it's in the help docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-tiled.html

Comment: @blong I've [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1653232), mark yourself as affected at the top if you are affected :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 16.04 from 15.10. I was able to solve it as follows:

- access "CompizConfig Settings Manager"
- you might have to install it via

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```

  I had installed it previously already in 14.04.
- In "CompizConfig Settings Manager", category "Window Management", the option "Grid" was disabled (probably due to conflicts with new settings in the "General Options"). After activating it and accepting to overwrite the settings in the "General Options" part, I got the previous behaviour restored.

Comment: That worked and yes, there were conflicts but it is now sorted. Thanks Dirk!

Answer (score 2):

Currently in Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS (using Unity) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> *does* work.

Comment: Yes, sanity. Btw, for those wondering - in most cases, Super == Windows key.