# Window snapping broken in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz

I can't get window snapping to work in 16.04 LTS. It has worked previously, and stopped working at some time many months ago. Neither dragging the windows with the mouse, nor the Ctrl-Super-Arrow shortcut work.

Snapping *does* work on a guest login, so I'm guessing this is some config issue. I've tried deleting my compiz config as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/371644/49798), but no luck. I also tried running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure compiz`, but not luck. What else can I do?

This is all running on a Intel Core i5-3317U with integrated graphics and the default drivers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know what is the origin of the issue but it seems like an update has overriden some key bindings and options in compiz, to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then in the windows management options (from the left side panel) check the grid plugin (on the right side). When you click it it will prompt a message warning you that some keybindings are conflicting with others from the general options plugins, click on resolve the issues and replace all the keybindings with those of the grid plugin.

After this snapping and maximize/minimize should be working again.

[Credits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835161/ubuntu-16-04-tile-windows-no-longer-working)

Comment: I wound up reinstalling Ubuntu in the time between asking this question and your answer, which fixed the problem, so I can't verify if your solution works or not.

Comment: I can verify that this worked, at least for me.

Comment: worked for me too. I believe my settings were changed due to a bad shutdown